# DRF Serializer update list of nested objects

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I write the voting app project using Django-rest-framework. It has two models: question and nested answer. I want to **update** answers in question serializer upon request such as:

```
{
    "question":"question",
    "answers": [{"answer":"first updated answer"}, {"answer":"second update answer"}]
}
```

How can I do it properly? I tried to do it, but I deleting answers in every request and create new ones, because of that changes their id every time.

#### serializer.py

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    answers = AnswerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta(object):
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'question', 'answers', 'total_votes', 'user')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'total_votes', )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.question = validated_data.get('question', instance.question)
        instance.save()

        question = Question.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        Answer.objects.filter(question=question).delete()

        answers_data = validated_data.pop('answers')
        for answer_data in answers_data:
            Answer.objects.create(question=question, **answer_data)

        return instance
```

#### models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(verbose_name='Question', max_length=255)
    total_votes = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total Votes', default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, verbose_name='Question', related_name='answers',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(verbose_name='Answer', blank=True, max_length=255)
    votes_count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Count of Votes', default=0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just figured this after hours of documentation surfing:

#### serializer.py

```py
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # this is IMPORTANT, without this the 'id' field won't appear in validated data
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, write_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Answer

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    answers = AnswerSerializer(many=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        answer_data = validated_data.pop("answers")

        remove_items = { item.id: item for item in instance.answers.all() }

        for item in answer_data:
            item_id = item.get("id", None)

            if item_id is None:
                # new item so create this
                instance.answers.create(**item)
            elif remove_items.get(item_id, None) is not None:
                # update this item
                instance_item = remove_items.pop(item_id)
                Answer.objects.filter(id=instance_item.id).update(**item)

        for item in remove_items.values():
            item.delete()

        for field in validated_data:
            setattr(instance, field, validated_data.get(field, getattr(instance, field)))
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):

    if 'answers' in validated_data:
        answer_ids_new = []
        answer_ids_pre = instance.answers.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
        for answer in validated_data.pop('answers'):
            ans, _created = Answer.objects.get_or_create(**answer)
            ans.question = instance
            ans.save()
            answer_ids_new.append(ans.id)

        delete_ids = set(answer_ids_pre) - set(answer_ids_new)
        Answer.objects.filter(id__in=delete_ids).delete()
    for item, value in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance, item, value)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Note: I didn't tried the solution

Comment: the id is still changing.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide details based on ManZzup's answer.

Firstly a list serializer is required in order to update a list of objects using a serializer.

```
class LineListUpdateSerializer(ListSerializer):
    def update(
        self,
        instance,
        validated_data,
    ) :
        # get the existing items
        existing_lines_mapping = {
            item.id: item
            for item in instance
            # item.id: item for item in instance.lines.all()
        }
        result = []
        for data in validated_data:
            # check if the items in the list are already in the Database
            item_id = data.get("id", None)
            if item_id is None:
                # item has no ID. Which means its a new object
                result.append(self.child.create(data))
            elif existing_lines_mapping.get(item_id, None) is not None:
                # if the item is in the database, put it in the update list
                result.append(
                    self.child.update(
                        existing_lines_mapping.pop(item_id),
                        data,
                    )
                )
        # Perform deletions.
        for poi in existing_lines_mapping.values():
            # check which items are in the database, but not in the request / validated data.
            # if there are item in the current database which are not in the request data,
            # it means user has deleted it. Therefore, delete the item.
            poi.delete()

        return result
```

Now create a serializer and mention this as `the` list serializer.

```
class LineSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Line
        fields = "__all__"
        list_serializer_class = LineListUpdateSerializer
```

Check the id field declared on the serialier. Above `LineSerializer` can be called from anywhere to update a list of objects. I will provide an example where its being called from another serializer update method:

```
class AnotherSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    lines = LineSerializer(many=True)
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        lines = validated_data.pop('lines')
        
        serializer = self.fields['lines']
        serializer.update(instance.lines.all(), lines)
        ............
        
        super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

The provided code is example code and may not run but can be modified easily to work.